# Graphing a Custom Function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration, function-construction

I'm trying to make a graph of a function involving several steps, steps that I can't put straight into the Plot[ ] function. Here is the outline of the process:

- Two real numbers, A and B, are defined, which determine the coefficients to a system of differential equations.
- Mathematica solves the system for me (initial conditions are supplied) and returns the solutions.
- I take one of the solutions and integrate it (a definite integral), which produces a number, the final output.

You can see this is a process which takes two inputs and produces an output, but not as a simple function. What I want to do is make a graph plotting the final output as a function of A and B. Apologies if there's a simple fix, I've tried to search the documentation thoroughly.

#### Edit

Here is the code I am working with

```
A = 1.5; B = 2; 

Comatrix = 
  {{-(A + 2*B), 3*B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {A, -(A + 3*B), 4*B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, A, -(A + 4*B), 5*B, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, A, -(A + 5*B), 6*B, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, A, -(A + 6*B), 7*B, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, A, -(A + 7*B), 8*B, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A, -(A + 8*B), 9*B, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A, -(A + 9*B), 10*B}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A, -(10*B)}}; 

Nmatrix[t_] = {N2[t], N3[t], N4[t], N5[t], N6[t], N7[t], N8[t], N9[t], N10[t]}; 

system = Derivative[1][Nmatrix][t] == Comatrix . Nmatrix[t];

sol = 
  DSolve[
    {system, 
     N2[0] == 1, N3[0] == 0, N4[0] == 0, N5[0] == 0, N6[0] == 0, N7[0] == 0, 
     N8[0] == 0, N9[0] == 0, N10[0] == 0}, 
    {N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10}, t]; 

{N2ans[t_], N3ans[t_], N4ans[t_], N5ans[t_], N6ans[t_], 
     N7ans[t_], N8ans[t_], N9ans[t_], N10ans[t_]} = 
  {N2[t], N3[t], N4[t], N5[t], N6[t], N7[t], N8[t], N9[t], N10[t]} /. Flatten[sol]; 

f[t_] = 2*B*N2ans[t]; 
Integrate[t*f[t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

> `0.326222`

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html.en

Comment: If this is your actual problem, then `MatrixExp[]` would be an easier way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) in a comment, the solution to the ODEs is given by `MatrixExp`.  So, the integrand in the final line of code is,

```
s = MatrixExp[Comatrix t] [[1,1]];
```

which is a rather lengthy `RootSum`.  As verification,

```
NIntegrate[2 B s /. A -> 1.5 /. B -> 2], {t, 0, Infinity}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0733787, 0.326222} *)
```

which reproduces the sample result in about a tenth of a second.  `s` can be used for plotting, for instance by

```
Flatten[ParallelTable[{A, B, NIntegrate[t 2 B s, {t, 0, Infinity}]}, 
    {A, 0.1, 1.0, 0.1}, {B, 0.1, 1.0, 0.1}], 1];
ListPlot3D[%, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {A, B, f}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: `MatrixExp[]` supports the "action form", so you can write the solution as `First[MatrixExp[Comatrix t, UnitVector[9, 1]]]`.

Comment: @J.M.  Or, I could write `MatrixExp[Comatrix t][[1,1]]`

Comment: Yes indeed, but for a large enough matrix, the action form often takes less effort to compute since it only generates a vector and not the full exponential.

Comment: @J.M.  Great point, which I did not know.  Thanks.

Comment: One more question. I'm trying to graph A and B against the integral of 2Bt*N2, but the label on this graph is just N2. Is that a mislabelling?

Comment: @ShafiNoss  Yes, I mislabeled the vertical axis; now corrected.